# Como enlazar un Bootstrap.css a un elemento DIV de html?

Tags: php, html, css

en este caso presento un diseño de mi pagina que es style.css, pero estoy insertando un diseño especial para un multiselect...entonces ese diseño requiere que descargue bootstrap-multiselect.css y bootstrap.min.css , pero lo que quiero es que solamente actue sobre un div en mi pagina la cual esta guardada con index.php ... como podria enlazarlos?

Comment: Hola.. podrias mirar [ask]?? en general se pide que digas que has probado hasta ahora...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma en que podrías resolver esto sería ampliar tu CSS para ese div. 
Digamos, por ejemplo, que le das a la división WYSIWYG una ID de HTMLEditable.

puedes apuntar a ese div con tu CSS y todos los CSS dentro de ese div.

El css anterior solo se aplicará a ese div. Entonces es solo un caso de encontrar el CSS correcto que necesitas en ese div.

Tenga en cuenta que puede necesitar anular / restablecer el CSS de ese div para detener su bootstrap3 que se le aplica.

Puede usar less para que sea todo más fácil.

Fuente: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483666/enable-css-stylesheet-for-only-one-div-and-its-contents

Comment: entonces este codigo                                                    #HTMLEditable {
      // importar el CSS modal
       @import "bootstrap.css";
    }                                                                                                                tengo que añadir a un archivo HTMLEditable.less y entonces importar  mis bootstrap verdad?

Answer (score 0):

probablemente lo que necesites hacer es:

1.- Buscar saber si no existe un archivo `css` que de el estilo *boostrap* para ese componente que quieres usar en tu proyecto.
y/o

2.- Verificar usando el "inspector" de *chrome* o *firefox* que estilos realmente se están usando para ese componente y ver en que linea y que archivo utiliza, lo demás, lo eliminas.